# tcp_outgoing_address: cannot connect to website

Tags: proxy, linux-mint, squid

I have a LinuxMint running in a virtual box. I have installed a squid3 proxy server and it is working.

However, if I want to add a tcp_outgoing_address it is not working.

I am using the default configuration and just added the following line at the end:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 51.51.51.51
```

But after restarting the server I always get an error: The requested URL cannot be retrieved

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the IP address from which the connections originate? If this is an attempt to use your public address from an internal network, it won't work.